# Как работает директива try_files?

Tags: nginx, php

У меня тут возникли некоторые разногласия с директивой `try_files`, прошу просветить. Я думал, что она по очереди перебирает переданные параметры, пока не найдет рабочий, однако в следующем случае это поведение слегка отличается:

```
location / {
    try_files /web$uri /web$uri/ /app/app_dev.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    # root смотрит в корень symfony-проекта (не в /web!), app_dev.php я перекинул в /app
    set $fsn /app/app_dev.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index app/app_dev.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param script_filename $document_root$fsn;
}
```

([полный конфиг](http://pastebin.com/89MMjccE))

Этот хардкод работает при любом запросе, кроме `/`. При запросе `/` он напрочь отказывается подцеплять приложение ([полный дебаг-лог запроса](http://pastebin.com/YLyvd0Vb)), и у меня вообще ощущение, что try_files останавливается после первой же неудачи; Location при этом абсолютно точно берется правильный. Отдельный вопрос - что я такого сделал, что в логе появилось `recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)`.

В трекере nginx не нашел ничего похожего по try_files, из чего сделал вывод, что это у меня пули почему-то не ушли. ЧЯДНТ?

Версия nginx - 1.4.6, ОС - виртуалка lubuntu 14.04.1 x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте такую замену:

```
    -index index.html index.htm app_dev.php;
    +index index.html index.htm;
```

или вообще без index-а, реализовав его через try_files.

Что мешает обновить nginx?

Comment: @kolpak

> Попробуйте такую замену

безрезультатно

> или вообще без index-а, реализовав его через try_files.

безрезультатно

> Что мешает обновить nginx?

Последняя версия в репе, вряд ли на подакшене будет новей. Да и опять же, конкретно сейчас цель - не победить, а разобраться.

Comment: А вот это не смущает?

    2014/09/08 18:36:57 [error] 10439#0: *29 directory index of "/srv/http/hosts/ambinight.com/web/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: ambinight.debug, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "ambinight.debug"
    2014/09/08 18:36:57 [debug] 10439#0: *29 http finalize request: 403, "/web/?" a:1, c:1

Comment: @kolpak, вообще не очень, потому что текущую ситуацию я воспринимаю так:

1. В этом случае try\_files должен пробовать следующий вариант.
2. Папка подключена как shared folder, права на нее 770, юзер nginx закинут в группу владельцев vboxsf, executable bit на папках стоит - со стороны фс все должно быть гладко.
3. Все запросы, кроме рутового, спокойно разрешаются.
4. Индекс не обязан существовать в папке, в каком-нибудь прокси-конфиге его не будет никогда.

Тем не менее, что следует делать-то? Почему nginx валится на первой папке без индекса?

Comment: Думаю так:

* поставить свежий nginx (в 1.7.2 был фикс в try_files)

* добавить именованный location для обработки динамики

* добавить в location / 

    error_page 403 404 = @php;